# javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory cannot be created

Tags: java, tomcat, xsd, xsd-validation

Got below exceptions, when I tried to run my web application using tomcat(on server start up).[upgraded java 7 to java 8 and tomcat 7 to 8.5]

Jar used:   xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar

> SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
>       javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory cannot be created
>       at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:414)
>       at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder._newFactory(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:218)
>       at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder.newFactory(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:145)
>       at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:213)
>       at com.sun.faces.util.Util.createSchemaFactory(Util.java:237)
>       at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.initStatics(DbfFactory.java:247)
>       at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.(DbfFactory.java:209)
>       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.(ConfigManager.java:892)
>       at config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:652)
>       at nfig.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:324)
>       at ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/wlfullclient.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:1: Illegal provider-class name: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:245)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader.parseLine(ServiceLoader.java:272)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:307)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$200(ServiceLoader.java:185)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:357)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
>       at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder$2.run(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:403)
>       at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryFinder$2.run(SchemaFactoryFinder.java:399)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at

Comment: Java8 and tomcat8.5 used.

Answer (score 0):

Took wlfullclient.jar from my QA server and placed same in local upgraded tomcat.

When I compared I found QA's wlfullclient.jar size was much bigger than what I had in my local tomcat. Then I thought lets try it out with this. and that worked.

Thanks

Comment: I am faced to the same issue, and it was because I was compiling with Java 8 instead of 7.